# Trying to start up kafka server, after starting zookeeper, but getting ERROR Invalid config, exiting abnormally

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to set up a kafka server for a project. I was following this guide - https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart . I ran zookeper successfuly, but when I try to start the kafka server, I get this error bellow. I tried different pathing to the config properties, but I get the same message.

```
bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat C:\Users\Atanas0104\Documents\kafka_2.12-2.3.0\config\server.properties
[2019-08-15 18:00:20,434] INFO Reading configuration from: C:\Users\Atanas0104\Documents\kafka_2.12-2.3.0\config\server.properties (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig)
log4j:ERROR Failed to rename [C:\Users\Atanas0104\Documents\kafka_2.12-2.3.0/logs/server.log] to [C:\Users\Atanas0104\Documents\kafka_2.12-2.3.0/logs/server.log.2019-08-15-17].
[2019-08-15 18:00:20,436] ERROR Invalid config, exiting abnormally (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain)
org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig$ConfigException: Error processing C:\Users\Atanas0104\Documents\kafka_2.12-2.3.0\config\server.properties
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parse(QuorumPeerConfig.java:156)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:104)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:81)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "initial.rebalance.delay.ms"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:589)
        at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:631)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parseProperties(QuorumPeerConfig.java:244)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parse(QuorumPeerConfig.java:152)
        ... 2 more
Invalid config, exiting abnormally
```

This is the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mistake is **you are running zookeeper-server-start.bat with kafka server .properties**,you need to try with  kafka-server-start.bat 
1) first go to folder where kafka was there and try this

```
.\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties
```

follow the link https://dzone.com/articles/running-apache-kafka-on-windows-os

Comment: Thank you for replying! It worked. Really silly oversight on my part.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `server.properties` is bad, I downloaded it and I went through the same situation, I only changed the last line from

```
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
```

to

```
initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
```

And it did work.